# NDEigensystem in a complicated case

Tags: differential-equations, numerics, eigenvalues

Apologies for a boring question.

I am trying to modify the [standard Mathematica example](https://www.wolfram.com/language/11/differential-eigensystems/find-the-spectrum-of-a-schrdinger-operator.html) for my needs.

The only differences in my case are:

- A more complicated potential (double-well, grows rapidly).
- I'm interested in small values of $\hbar$.

  ```
  h = 0.01;
  V[x_] := -x^2 + x^6;
  \[ScriptCapitalL] = 3^(3/2)/2 (-h^2*u''[x] + V[x]*u[x]);
  xmax = 1.2; xmin = -xmax;
  {vals, funs} = 
  NDEigensystem[\[ScriptCapitalL], u[x], {x, xmin, xmax}, 10, Method ->     {"SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", {"MeshOptions" -> {MaxCellMeasure -> 0.05}}}}];
  Show[Plot[Evaluate[h*funs + vals], {x, xmin, xmax}],  Plot[V[x], {x, xmin, xmax}], PlotRange -> {{xmin, xmax}, {-.1, .2}},  AxesOrigin -> {-3, 0}]
  ```

As you will see, Mathematica is not finding the lowest energies. I'm wondering if anyone could suggest a possible solution. Not sure which options of NDEigensystem  to adjust. (Or probably there's a better way to solve the problem).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am assuming you are concerned about not finding the negative values. `NDEigensystem` discretizes the PDE and then calls `Eigensystem` to find the eigenvalues and vectors. If you read the [Details and Options section of Eigenvalues](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Eigenvalues.html) you will find the 4th bullet point that states:

"If they [the eigenvalues*] are numeric, eigenvalues are sorted in order of decreasing absolute value."

(*) added my be.

Here are a few things you can try:

You can use the direct solver and get all eigenvalues and vectors.

```
{vals, funs} = 
  NDEigensystem[\[ScriptCapitalL], u[x], {x, xmin, xmax}, All, 
   Method -> {"SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", \
{"MeshOptions" -> {MaxCellMeasure -> 0.1}}}, 
     "Eigensystem" -> {"Direct"}}];

Min[vals]
-0.9482580993140183`
```

This is slow. As an alternative you could try to shift the eigenvalues:

```
{vals, funs} = 
  NDEigensystem[\[ScriptCapitalL], u[x], {x, xmin, xmax}, 10, 
   Method -> {"SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", \
{"MeshOptions" -> {MaxCellMeasure -> 0.1}}}, 
     "Eigensystem" -> {"Arnoldi", "Shift" -> -1}}];
Min[vals]
-0.948258
```

And as a third option you could make use of FEAST and try to find the eigenvalues in a specified range:

```
{vals, funs} = 
  NDEigensystem[\[ScriptCapitalL], u[x], {x, xmin, xmax}, 25, 
   Method -> {"SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", \
{"MeshOptions" -> {MaxCellMeasure -> 0.01}}}, 
     "Eigensystem" -> {"FEAST", "Interval" -> {-2.0, 0.}}}];
Min[vals]
-0.948479
```

In the last case I also made use of a finer grid.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much!!